# Subsonic version

Tags: subsonic

I've got the 2.2 version of Subsonic but the SubSonic.dll is versioned as 2.1.1.0 is that fine?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in the zip file distribution. It has several copies of 2.1.1.0. It is not fine. 2.2.0 is in the root of the zip distribution, use that.